# Get custom field in system.xml

Tags: system.xml

In system.xml file, I have declared a button as below:

```
<import_customer translate="label comment">
                <label>Import Customer</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[Import customers data]]></comment>
                <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
                <frontend_model>cemimport/adminhtml_system_config_form_button</frontend_model>
                <action_url>module/importer/customers</action_url>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </import_customer>
```

Is there any way for me to get `<action_url>` value inside the _getElementHtml method?

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Button extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->getSections()
```

hopefully `Mage::app()->getConfig()` returns a `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config` class

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
 protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
```

Then in your template file:

```
<?php echo $this->getButtonHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `_getElementHtml` method you can retrieve the value of the `<action_url>` field from system.xml like this:

```
$data = $element->getOriginalData();
$actionUrl = $data['action_url'];
```

Or like this, checking if the field exists:

```
$data = $element->getOriginalData();
$actionUrl = NULL;
if (isset($data['action_url']))
{
    $actionUrl = $data['action_url'];
}
```